# What is the difference between coverage_exclusions vs exclusions in sonar?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

What is the difference between `coverage_exclusions` vs `exclusions` in sonar? example:

```
"sonar": {
    "exclusions": "gulpfile.js, ...",
    "coverage_exclusions": "gulpfile.js, ..., server/models/*.js",
    "quality_gate": "...",
    "server_id": "SONAR-main"
  },
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`sonar.coverage.exclusions` excludes some files from the test coverage metrics but those files are still analyzed: other metrics, duplications, coding rules...

`sonar.exclusions` completely excludes some files from the analysis: those files don't appear at all in SonarQube.

See https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/

`sonar.exclusions` and `sonar.coverage.exclusions` are standard property names for SonarQube. I don't know how the tool you use feeds these properties to the analysis based on your configuration file.